# State not getting updated in promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have below states -

```
   const[value1,setValue1]=useState();
    const[value2,setValue2]=useState();
    
    function promiseExecutionMethod()
    {
      let Value1Promise=Collection.fetValue()
                                 .then((res)=>
                                          { 
                                             setValue1(res); 
                                           });
    
    let Value2Promise=Collection.fetValue()
                                 .then((res)=>
                                          { 
                                             setValue2(res); 
                                           });

Promise.all([Value1Promise,Value2Promise]).then(([result1,result2])=>{
  console.log(value1);   //cannot see updated states here
  console.log(value2);   //cannot see updated states here
}


    }

useEffect(()=>{
console.log(value1); //can see updated state
},[value1]);

useEffect(()=>{
console.log(value2); //can see updated state
},[value2]);
```

Here I am changing states in promise. UseEffect also shows changed states.

But not able to see changed states in Promise.All(..).Then method.

Comment: The state is not updated synchronously. So when you do console.log inside your Promise.all, it still has the old value. That's why useEffect is usually used in those cases

Comment: @szczocik is right. Also, you have a typo. It's not `Promise.All()`, but `Promise.all()` :)

Answer (score 0):

I made use of another state -

```
const[render,setRender]=useState(0);
```

and in Promise.all([..]).then(([..])

```
Promise.All([Value1Promise,Value2Promise]).then(([result1,result2])=>{
  setRender(render+1);
}
```

Through this , I am able to access updated states.